# OpenTok iOS SDK - how to know the current version?

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

how do I know which is the current version of the OpenTok iOS SDK installed on my project please ?

Answer (score 4):

Compile and run the app from within XCode and you will see a banner as shown below for 2.10.2 version.

`2017-03-30 11:52:49.237431 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] ------------------------------------------------
2017-03-30 11:52:49.237522 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] OpenTok iOS Library, Rev.2
2017-03-30 11:52:49.237661 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] This build was born on Feb 23 2017 at 09:55:38
2017-03-30 11:52:49.249858 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] Version: 2.10.2.2083-ios
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250112 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] libOpenTokObjC:8eb18711043f86f3070443a583eba2374771ec04
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250289 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] libOTKit:edb2cecf59f96e813dcdfd14b031f89757cf8ba5
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250459 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] WebRTC:ca7fe7ea0257ae5e4318549abbe7c0f79063865e
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250557 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] Copyright 2016 TokBox, Inc.
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250637 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
2017-03-30 11:52:49.250718 1.Hello-World[7170:1471305] ------------------------------------------------`